# How to resize UIView while moving, just like SnapGuide?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I've a scroll view which has several UIViews that shows information to the user. This scrollview supports only horizontal scrolling and when user starts scrolling from left to right or vise versa, the center view should be bigger and the previous and next views should be smaller (as shown in the below view).

[image]

I'm able to do this by changing the frames of all the views that appear on the scrollviews. But the animation is not smooth. I just want to resize the views while scrolling according to their position. Is there anyway to do this? Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you could look at these links

[UIScrollview make the current Image Larger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12658633/uiscrollview-make-the-current-image-larger)

Or I can provide a better solution to you with **iCarousel**. Please refer to it and I think this might help you , and its pretty easy to integrate too :)

Comment: Perfect, I was looking for the same for years. BTW, do you know how decrease the speed of Carousel?

Comment: Yep why not, why dont u go through the documentation of the iCarousel method, all kinds of methods are there, specially the speed decreasing one :) ..

Answer (score 2):

This might be what you are looking for [**CGAffineTransformScale**](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGAffineTransformScale). You need to set your UIViews transformation property, for example

```
CGAffineTransform transformRatio = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, factorX, factorY);
myView.transform = transformRatio;
```

**factorX** and **factorY** are the values by which to scale your views width and height.
When you view starts scrolling in and out you need to set the corresponding factors.